# how do i fetch a mysql record then assign each field to different variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with various fields `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `phone` etc... Each one has a unique id.

How can I use PHP to retrieve the fields then assign them each to a separate PHP variable for example when it gets the user record by using the id it then assigns `firstname` to `$firstname`, `lastname` to `$lastname` etc...

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table
        WHERE 'id' = $id";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $firstname = $row['firstname']; $lastname = $row['lastname'];
    //and so on for other fields
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? Please post it

Comment: this is the code I am trying but it keeps giving me undefinded variable error when i try to call $firstname - am working with the one filed initally to try get the main coding correct and then can add the other fields i require.

Comment: You could do it with extract().  But you really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps.

```
<?php

$query = "select * from some_table where id=some_id";

$exe = mysqli_query($db, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($exe))
{
  $field1 = $row['field1'];
  $field2 = $row['field2'];
  $field3 = $row['field3'];
  $field4 = $row['field4'];
  $field5 = $row['field5'];
}
```

Comment: You can also use extract function on $row variable like:
    extract($var_array);
    then use it as $field1, $field2, $firstname, $lastname, etc.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Ok thanks for the help it is now showing as i wanted really appreciate the fast and usefull help cheers

Comment: thanks @jetblack for letting me know another way to do so. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tableName`";
$run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run){
$firstname= $row['firstname'];
$lastname= $row['lastname'];
$email= $row['email'];
$email= $row['phone'];
```

i dont know if that what you mean,

PS:`$con` is the variable that is used in config file to connect to database, hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

> when it gets the user record by using the id it then assigns `firstname` to `$firstname`, `lastname` to `$lastname` etc...

Something you could do is declare a PHP variable and use a variable for its name. You use the double `$$` symbol to do that:

```
<?php

$varName  = 'username';

$$varName = 'James';

echo $username; // will print 'James'
```

Comment: Hands off from variable variables! One of the worst constructs of PHP...not readable, nor maintainable, just cnfusing everyone...

Comment: Yeah pretty horrible to use right ;) but thought I'd show it here. Actually, I remember using it once on a website's router in order to automatically create PHP variables based on the received AJAX data.

Comment: ;) well I also used it years ago until me and other devs got horrible issues on debugging